# How to write a PHP batch file that will execute a series of PHP files one after another?

Tags: php

I know I can set up a cron for each of the individual PHP files, but is there a way for a cron to run one PHP file that calls a list of files in a specific order. For example, It should only call the second file if the first file has completed.

Comment: interesting, have you concidered using php's system function ?

Comment: what type of files do you want php to run? other php scripts (can just include the file) or bash scripts (http://us.php.net/exec)?

Comment: They are going to be executed at the prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using php's `system` function.

You can find the doc here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

And you can use the return_value parameter and compare it against FALSE to check for failure

You can also use `shell_exec` ([http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)) which has almost the same effect

Comment: An alternative to `system()` is to simply state the command using backticks, like so: `\`ls\``

Answer (score -1):

If you would add a variable like `$is_it_true = true` when the script runs, and write `( $is_it_true ) ? include 'anotherfile.php':''`

Then it'd do it. if you need more then just use it otherwise make it true by default, and make it false when error happens, and let it go inside if's.

Comment: including another php file in another just to run it is just horrible : consider all the variable conflicts that could arise just from that :)

Comment: yup, on the limit, if you are an experienced programmer you can be sure you won't have problems, but on the other hand, the chances are high that your code will act randomly, if you see what i mean..